# Running Quartz Scheduler Daily on Cluster Environment

Tags: java, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

The requirement is to run a java application periodically (say everyday for an example) to send out email/SMS notification to customers. The environment is cluster / high availability where more than one node will be active at the same time. This application is to be deployed on all the nodes but only one should start and run even though all of them are configured to run. How to achieve this. In teh Java application, Quartz Scheduler is used.

Also need some guidance on how to deploy this java application on Linux machine (like Cron job or some other way). The requirement is that this application should start whever the server system starts and will run forever until the server goes down. When the server starts again, this job should also start automatically.

Comment: Maintain the details in the database, if application in one node starts sending email or simply starts the application, update the specific database table and check whether notification sending application has been started or not. If application has already been started then application in other node should not start.

Comment: You have to mention transaction system for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
The requirement is to run a java application periodically (say everyday for an example) to send out email/SMS notification to customers.
```

This can be achieved by Quartz by creating a Job and corresponding trigger which will fire at particular time.

```
The environment is cluster / high availability where more than one node will be active at the same time. This application is to be deployed on all the nodes but only one should start and run even though all of them are configured to run. How to achieve this
```

Quartz scheduler supports the clustering mechanism via database.If two or more schedulers have same name but different instance id they will form the cluster,only caveat is that all application nodes should point to the same database.

```
Also need some guidance on how to deploy this java application on Linux machine (like Cron job or some other way).
```

When Quartz is doing the work of scheduling there is no need to create a linux cron job.

```
When the server starts again, this job should also start automatically.
```

Quartz has provision to handle the misfired triggers so if an application goes down ,quartz will scan the miss fired triggers on start up of application and schedule them.

For getting the above things to work you should use JDBC Jobstore in quartz instead of RAMJobStore

Comment: 1. Can you help me to get some examples for implementing JDBC Jobstore for cluster environment. 2. Also one point which is not answered is, I have the quartz scheduler as stand alone java application with main method. Some one has to start this application for the first time. When the server is rebooted, how to start this job automatically? Any help on these two points would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can take some guidance from this link https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-email-scheduling-example/  .For the second question,all the applications in the production environment do not reboot their system until it is critical emergency.You can run the application in background by using 'noop' so in case you kill your session application will be up.